# ScreenShot of entire webpage using selenium-webdriver/ rc rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am trying to take screenshot of an given link using selenium-webdriver. I am using the below script

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to 'URL'
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
driver.quit
```

This is working fine but it only take screenshot of the visible area. I have also tried

```
driver.capture_entire_page_screenshot('test.png','');
```

and

```
driver.capture_entire_page_screenshot('test.png');
```

but I am getting  undefined method `capture_entire_page_screenshot'` error any suggestions how can I achieve this.
Update, also tried the below option which is working but only taking the screenshot of visible/ full screenshot. With visible area I mean if my page has scroll its not taking the screenshot of the full page.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'selenium/client'
require 'selenium-rc'

@selenium = Selenium::Client::Driver.new("localhost", 4444,"*chrome", "someurl", 1000);
@selenium.start

@selenium.open ""

@selenium.wait_for_page_to_load "3000"
@selenium.send(:sleep, 4) # Wait for Flash and other crap to load
@selenium.capture_entire_page_screenshot('/path/to/save/screenshot.png', '');
@selenium.stop
```

and also is there a way to use proxy in this?

Comment: what do you mean by visible area?..Anyways capture_entire_page_screenshot is a method of Selenium RC not webdriver.

Comment: @Abhi_Mishra Could you please suggest me then which method to use. With visible area I mean, If my site has scroll. It won't capture the scrollable area or in short it will just capture the current viewport.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue for the Selenium contributors group and apparently is dependent upon a bug being fixed in Chrome (Chromium).  See this thread:

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294

The thread has some hacks to work around the issue until (if?) Google fixes the aforementioned bug